# Html thumbnails

Tags: javascript, html, thumbnails

When we open a new tab in google chrome it shows thumbnails as this.
[image: focus on thumbnails] .  Is there a way that I can also use this thumbnail facility on my html webpage such that I just pass the url's of various sites and it shows in the same manner. I can not use fixed images as the content on the websites (I wish to display as thumbnails) keeps on changing.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible [to get a screenshot of a page with client side code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots/6678156#6678156), the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) will prevent you from doing it to arbitrary third party sites.

You would need to look for a server side solution to generate your screenshots. There are several tools that could help ([PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) spring to mind). You would need to write a web server that you could use to pass a URL over and get a screenshot back.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WordPress, there is some information about it [here](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/02/automated-take-screenshots-website-free/)

There is a plugin to download, but there is also a code example.